# How to implement user roles in Asp.Net core views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, authorization

I am working on project where I have to implement user roles and rules. In the Api part I am using Authorization attributes but in client (views) how can put show and hide functionality on button and other html controls. I want to avoid razors if condition because it put lots of logics in html side and later on views get more complicated and hard to maintain.

Can anyone have any better idea to accomplish this without if or other conditions in views.

Comment: Other than having different views, you would need conditional statements in the view

Comment: is there any way to put data elements in html controls and override view engine to check those element to show or hide before rendering to client?

Comment: No. But another option is create your own `HtmlHelper` extension methods which accept the role as a parameter (and you either return the html, or `null` based on the role)